# is it possible to know whether someone else has opened file in ec2-linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, vi

We guys work collaboratively. Sometimes more then 1 have opened same file in vi editor. Can I know there who else has opened that file in amazon ec2 instance?

Also if I can know what changes made by other ..

Comment: I suspect this will get migrated to U&L or to stackoverflow.  Check out http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic.  Thanks!

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Get proper version control, such as git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `vim`, it uses a swap file to track in-progress changes, and will typically notify you if someone else is currently modifying the same file.  However, this should be considered an unreliable safety net, and not something to plan on.  In other words, it **might** work, but it is definitely the wrong solution.

If you have multiple people editing the same file(s), and collaborating on the same work, you should be using a Revision Control system.  There are dozens (if not hundreds) of available options, many of them free and open source.  Using one of these is the **correct** solution.

I'd start by looking into one or more of the more popular Version Control Systems (and maybe review some Wikipedia [articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) on the topic to understand what they do and how they work).  Popular choices that will probably work well for you include: [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/), [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/), [Git](http://git-scm.com/), [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), and [Monotone](http://www.monotone.ca/).  Personally, I'm a big fan of Fossil for smaller projects, but any of those listed will probably work just fine for you.